# Solr returned an error #404 Not Found for url http://localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true

Tags: solr

The error above occurs when I imported xml data into my Solr (v4.3.0), and I just changed my collection name, while nothing different from example file.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you also update the solr.xml with the collection name and path values ?

Comment: Yes, I did update my solr.xml.

Comment: What all did u change with renaming the collection ? Can you post the solr.xml

Comment: Visit /solr to see the admin console. You should be able to see the active collections. Is your collection listed?

Comment: Yes, my collection is listed. I restart everything, and then it's ok now, thanks the same!

Answer (score 16):

try to access the following URL : IP:PORT/solr/NAME_OF_YOUR_CORE/update?commit=true

Answer (score 2):

I am using Solr 4.2.0 with Rails and no collections were setup by default. But 3 cores were setup by default (default, development, test). So I had to set :url in my solr config for sunspot to include the core name in the path like so...

`http://localhost:8982/solr/development/update?commit=true`

Pay attention that you are on the correct port (8981, 8982, 8983)

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr
    url: http://localhost:8982/solr/development
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the core is case-sensitive, make sure to write it correctly. It was the issue on my part.

So if your core's name is MyCore the url needs to be:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/MyCore/update`

and not, for example, `http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update`.